# Raspberry Pi Zero usb port not working and no network access

Tags: gpio, networking, pi-zero, usb-power, pitft

*I have a Raspberry Pi Zero V1.3.
I recently tried making a portable device running Retropie.*

I attached a TFT-screen using the ports on GPIO.
After a while I was trying to install modules for the screen and Pi just turned off itself.

I thought it was caused by the cable I soldered to the usb pins so I desoldered it and managed to turn on pi again.
But now the usb ports are not working.
I tried plugging the usb cable in the other port and vice versa but no luck.

I was using a Usb to Ethernet adapter to connect it to the net.
*So now I am not able to control the raspberry pi or connect it to the network because the usb port is not working.*

For the TFT screen I followed these steps:
https://www.itead.cc/blog/raspberry-pi-2-8-tft-add-on-touch-function

So how can I fix the usb port or how can I connect my Pi to the internet to use ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Your Pi has a serial port on GPIO pins 8 and 10 (see e.g. [this pinout](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/80667-102-2-338789/GPIO.png)).  If the OS you're running on the Zero has been configured to run a getty on that port you could use something [like this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) to log in over the serial port.

Remember that you can always pop the SD card and make any necessary configuration changes on another computer.  This can also give you a method for debugging things slowly:

- Write a script that generates diagnostic information and have it run when the system boots and write that information to a file.
- Pop the SD card, mount it on another system, and examine the generated file.
- Repeat as necessary.

The simplest way to run something when the system boots is to add your commands to `/etc/rc.local`